# Water, how do you make ripples

Tags: fluid-dynamics

How do I make a ripple effect in a bowl of water.  I have tried throwing small pebble sin but it just splashes and sinks.  I have read that I need to make the water a thicker liquid ie add glycerine, will this work and why?

Comment: Have you tried say, sticking your finger in the water and slowly bobbing it up and down? Any slow, smooth and oscillatory movement will generate ripples in water.

Comment: Shine a light on the water in the bowl and watch the reflection. It should just look like a simple mirror. Then drop in your pebble. The reflection will be all messed up for a little while. That's your ripples.

Answer (score 1):

Making water ripples in the bowel of water by throwing a pebble in it would be difficult an it will also be little bit bigger and faster to see it in a water bowel. Rather you can try vibrating the bowel at it's centre at the bottom of the bowel with something like electronic raser or a massage machine or you can just hit the bottom with a spoon the vibration will case small amplitude ripples to form on the surface of water. Yes if you add some thing to the water to make it make it a little thicker then according to me it will require a little bit more energy to form ripple.